# Using an LM386 with input and output transformers for isolation from power supply

Tags: lm386

The LM386 TI applications notes page 11 show an amplifier. Would like to use this chip  with complete isolation of the output speaker and with the addition of an isolated input speaker. Am using impedance matching transformers on input and output for speaker isolation from the power supply. Should the 10 mfd shown be polarized?

Comment: Please edit your question with a link to the app note in question.  While you're at it, a schematic showing how you propose to add a transformer would be nice.

Comment: If you're going to tie one end of the transformer to ground then you need a cap between the LM386 output and the transformer.  The LM386 output cannot go outside the rails, so it needs a blocking cap to drive something like a speaker or transformer primary.  The cap doesn't need to be polarized, but a polarized cap is  perfectly suitable, and possibly the least expensive solution.

Comment: The LM386 has such a low output power that it is usually powered from a little battery. are you going to use the input speaker as a boomy microphone? Then how will you prevent acoustical feedback howling if it can hear the output speaker?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the 10µF capacitor between pins 1 and 8 *can* be polarized, but it doesn't have to be.  If you use a polarized capacitor, have the negative side on pin 8.

This will give you a gain of 200.  If you want a different gain, you need to add a series resistor.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm386 - Datasheet ....